# My program gives wrong output

Tags: java

When I run it, computer counts only 1 3 5 7 9 ... indexes. For example, if I enter "Hello", computer counts 1-H,1-l and 1 o, it doesn't compute e and l(4th index).
What is wrong with it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class LetterCount {
public static void main(String[] args){
    final int Numchars=26;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] upper=new int[Numchars];
    int[] lower=new int[Numchars];
    char current='a';
    char current0='A';
    int pox=0;
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    String line=scan.nextLine();
    for(int ch=0; ch<line.length(); ch++){
        for(int other=0; other<26; other++){
            if(line.charAt(ch)==(char)(current+other))
                lower[other]++;
            if(line.charAt(ch)==(char)(current0+other))
                upper[other]++;
            else
                pox++;
        }
        ch++;
    }

for(int another=0; another<lower.length;another++)
    System.out.println((char)(another+'a')+"   " +lower[another]);
for(int b=0; b<lower.length;b++)
    System.out.println((char)(b+'A')+"   " +upper[b]);
System.out.println("non alphabetic characters: "+pox);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: remove the `ch++;` at the end of the outer for-loop ;)

Comment: this program counts letters of sentence, so it should give 1H 1 e 2l 1o

Comment: what a stupid  mistake, i'm studying for my final exam,so i am asleep :D @alfasin thank you

Answer (score 3):

It basically boils down to:

```
for (int ch = 0; ch < line.length(); ch++) {  // Increment per iteration
    doSomething();
    ch++;                                     // Increment within body
}
```

in which you increment `ch` *twice!*

You need to get rid of one of them and, since the usual way to do a `for` loop with known-in-advance number of iterations like this is to put the control variable modification into the `for` statement itself, I would suggest getting rid of the one in the loop body:

```
for (int ch = 0; ch < line.length(); ch++) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you increments ch twice, at the end of for expression and at the end of for loop.